# Login to google drive with accessToken

Tags: rest, oauth, google-drive-api, google-oauth, access-token

Is there any chance to sign-in to google drive using accessToken.I have user

account refresh token and accessToken i need to login with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A refresh token (or access token) only gives the application it was granted to the access that it was granted with.

Example:

> Application *super drive* requests access to a users drive account.

This will give

> application *super drive* access to a users drive account.

When a user authenticates your application they are granting you access to specific scopes.  In the above instance Drive.  The application will only have access to Google drive API.  Its the application itself you will not be able to login and access the web page for google drive.  Nor will you be able to install any other third party application and use the refresh token with that.  Users grant access to an application to access the data on their behalf.

**NO:**  Under no circumstances will you be able to login to a users Google account via any other means then your application accessing an API.

Even requesting the scope of login will only give you access to their information via the API.